# Converting Gmail based WebApp to Android

Tags: android, web-applications, gmail-api

I've developed a webapp using GMail API. It works well in the browser even Mobile browsers. I'm trying to convert to a Mobile App (apk) using some online converters, as I don't have App Dev experience. When I try to open the .apk, I get this error:

> Error 403: disallowed_useragent

Is there anyway to handle it in the Web App code itself without getting into Android App coding?